# Adding clickable SubMenu from view throws: BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Tags: android

I'm adding sub menu while I'm inside a class that extended from RelativeLayout:

```
@Override
protected void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu);
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Submenu");
    subMenu.add("SUB1");
    subMenu.add("SUB2");
}
```

And I'm showing the menu using:

```
showContextMenu();
```

Everything for now is good and the "Submenu" item is showing very well. While I'm clicking on "Submenu" item, it's generating this exception:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:542)
 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
 at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.show(MenuDialogHelper.java:95)
 at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onSubMenuSelected(ListMenuPresenter.java:139)
 at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchSubMenuSelected(MenuBuilder.java:266)
 at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:902)
 at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
 at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:173)
 at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:952)
 at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:302)
 at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1188)
 at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3009)
 at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3767)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Actually I don't understand the exception very well, and I don't see any example of how the sub menu will be displayed, I think it will be displayed in a popup dialog or something like that?

What I need to do is showing a menu item with sub items, I'm not inside an activity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution yet for that issue, I had to use [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) class and it works as I want to be.
You can use this good [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/android-app-menus/).